# R Language what is difference between rnorm and runif

Tags: r

What is the difference between the functions `rnorm` and `runif` in R?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @SrinivasaReddyChalla. It's not clear to me that this question is on-topic here (see our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq)). Are you wondering about the differences b/t the normal and uniform distributions? or about the nature of pseudorandom generation?

Comment: @SrinivasaReddyChalla, you can check the documentation of any R function via the syntax `?somefunction`. For example, to check the documentation for `runif`: open up an R session and type `?runif`.

Answer (score 26):

`rnorm` generates a random value from the normal distribution. `runif` generates a random value from the uniform.

Answer (score 22):

`rnorm(n, mean = , sd = )` is used to generate `n` normal random numbers with arguments `mean` and `sd`; while `runif(n, min = , max = )` is used to generate `n` uniform random numbers lie in the interval `(min, max)`.

Please check corresponding R help documents for details.